# Filtering Multiple input on a single json

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, uitableview, material-ui

I have a json file with object

```
obj= [{fname:"abhi",age:5,class:"ten",lanme:"kumar"
},{fname:"abhi",age:5,class:"ten",lanme:"kumar"
},{fname:"abhi",age:5,class:"ten",lanme:"kumar"
},{fname:"abhi",age:5,class:"ten",lanme:"kumar"
}]
```

which I display in the following table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gRJa.png)

i am trying to build a filter for the above table but I am not able to filter it out
Can anyone please help me on this

Note: Second Row each Column is a Filter for only that column that is Class searches only class  column not everything

And that search should populate in that table

Can anyone please help I am stuck here from ages on this specially with useState Hook
Stack Used : React & Javascript no third party library

Currently my filter is something like this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState({
    lastname: '',
    class: '',
    firstname: '',
  });
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    const searchValue = {
      ...value,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    setValue(searchValue);
    setCopyList(
      copyList.filter(item => item[e.target.name].includes(e.target.value))
    );
  };
```

currently what is happening is as soon as I search on each individual column it refreshes the search on the present values

Comment: Please include your attempt at building the filter.

Comment: I have added My Filter attempt on Top @mykaf

Answer (score 0):

first You make a generic function and then implement every input text
field. This solution is especially in react js and js.

```
 const searchByName = (name) => {
if (name !== "") {
  console.log(name);
  const res = data.filter((sd) => {
    return (
      sd.firstName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      sd.email.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search)
    );
  });
  console.log(res);
  setData(res);
} else {
  setData(dataFilter);
}
```

};

Comment: Thanks Hamza Ali, but what will happen If I need to have multiple search, In above approach what is happening is as soon as I try to interact with another column then the values of the table get set to that coulmn but a soon as  I switch to another column it again take it from fresh, I have also added my code on top kindly check once